Splunk: undefined setting in transforms.conf: python.version
When I generate app manifest using slim for a Splunk App, it gives the following warning:
slim generate-manifest: [WARNING] /opt/splunk/etc/apps/devtutorial/default/transforms.conf, line 4: Undefined setting in transforms.conf, stanza [dnslookup]: python.version

I am running the following slim command to generate App manifest from $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps location:
slim generate-manifest devtutorial -o devtutorial/app.manifest

Python version in my system is 3.8.19.
Help me, why the python.version attribute is giving a warning when it is a valid attribute?
